# Why is my method not properly detecting if an object is null?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am writing JUnit tests to test a method which adds a bus stop to a list of favorites. It should only add the stop to the list if the stop is either not null or the stop is not already in the list. This is the method I have for it:

```
public boolean addStop(BusStop stop) {
  if (stop == null || stops.contains(stop)) {
       return false;
  else {
       stops.add(stop);
       return true;
}
```

and this is my JUnit test:

```
public void testAddStop() {
  stops.add(stop1);
  stops.add(stop2);
  stops.add(stop3);
  stops.add(stop4); // Stops 1-4 are not null
  assertEquals(stops.size(), 4);
  stop5 = null;
  stops.add(stop5); // Stop 5 is null 
  assertEquals(stops.size(), 4);
}
```

When running the test the second assertEquals fails, saying it expected 5, but was actually 4. Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: There are 3 aspects to debugging: the input, the process and the output. You've given us the process and the output but left us guessing at the input.

Comment: Because you are using `stops.add(stop5)` directly instead of calling `addStop(stop5)`

Comment: How is it possible that the unit test can access the internal data structure `stops`?

Comment: @gtgaxiola ahh thank you, I must have overlooked that because they sound extremely similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in the JUnit "assert" method calls, the expected value goes first, then the test value.  Use `assertEquals(4, stops.size())`.  It should be expected 4, was 5.

Second, you're calling `stops.add(stop5)`, not the `addStop` method, so `null` is added.  Have your `test` method actually call `addStop`.